# google place search out of range

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Good morning,
I have a site where I would like to populate a select passing latitude and longitude of a place.
I have create many function in javascript to call google api place search to retrieve places.
The problem is that I retrieve an error `out of range`.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     function change_interest_point(city_id, map, lat, lng){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        $('.icon-place').each(function(index){
            val = $(this).attr('id');
            icon = $(this).data('icon');
            up206b.placesRequest('',myLatlng,'5000',[val],icon,map, 'interest-point');
        });
    }
});   



var up206b = {};
up206b.placesRequest = function(title,latlng,radius,types,icon,map, select)
{
    //Parameters for our places request
    var request = {
        location: latlng,
        radius: radius,
        types: types
    };

    var callPlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    callPlaces.search(request, function(results,status){
        $.each(results, function(i,place){
                var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
                $('#myselect').append('<option value="' + placeLoc.lat() + ', ' + placeLoc.lng() + '">' + place.name + '</option>');
        })
    });    
}
```

html:

```
<div id="airport" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="aquarium" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="bus_station" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="car_rental" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="casino" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="church" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="museum" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="night_club" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="park" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="restaurant" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="subway_station" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
<div id="train_station" class="icon-place" data-icon="icon.png">
```

And this is the error:

```
TypeError: this.b[Nb] is not a function


(269 out of range 57)
```

Logically if I remove the call of search places this error there isn't.

Comment: Can you provide complete code, a fiddle or a link to a live map that exhibits the issue?

Comment: where/how do you call change_interest_point() ?

Comment: I call it inside document.ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finded the solution.

I need to convert my map into a google map adding this line before the call to placeRequest

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map),mapOptions);
```